# Sparse cholesky factorization of CuSparseCSR matrix in Julia

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

I have a CuSparseCSR matrix “A” and I want to take complete or incomplete cholesky factorization of it, but crucially leave that factorization on the GPU, ideally using CUDA.jl? It seems that a lot of packages functionality has been moved into CUDA.jl, but the web is polluted with the old documentation.

Things I’ve tried:

1. CuSparse.jl - deprecated
2. CuArrays.jl - possibly deprecated, got this error trying to “add CuArrays” in the package manager
3. CuSolver.jl -deprecated

```
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package CUDAapi [3895d2a7]:
 CUDAapi [3895d2a7] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 0.5.0-4.0.0 or uninstalled
 └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — no versions left
```

4. Preconditioners.jl - only for CPU matrices
5. cholesky(A) - works but puts the factorization on the CPU

I want to be able to solve systems with GPU right hand sides, so I need the result on the GPU

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at LinearSolve at https://github.com/SciML/LinearSolve.jl

They are adding more and more methods and many of them are CUDA compatible.

Comment: LinearSolve.jl is an interface package rather than something that does the actual work. Solving sparse linear systems on GPU is very different from that on CPU and often cannot be conducted solely on GPU.